# Image autolayout issues after refreshing Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, autolayout, firebase-storage

I have a table view that is pulling data from firebase. When I load the app, everything looks fine, but then once it refreshes, the image flattens for some reason. I'm not sure if it's a Firebase, AutoLayout, or runtime error. Can someone please help?

**Example**

[image]

Comment: try calling cell.imageView.setNeedsDisplay() in cellForRow of TableView when it refreshes

Comment: @iOSGeek hm it didn't seem to work. If it helps, there's actually a UIlabel above the image as well where I'm combining the label, the image, and the name label together using UIStackView. Sometimes the UIlabel gets flattened too so I'm not sure where the error is coming from.

Comment: That looks like a constraint issue. In IB try selecting that imageView and Remove Constraints and see if that changes anything.